# Are there two separate reasons given for wanting to stone Jesus?

Tags: greek, john

Beginning in Chapter 5, John details how the Jews wanted to kill Jesus. First, the intent is described: *for making Himself equal to God* (5:18). Then the manner of death *they picked up stones to throw at him* (8:59). Finally:

> <sup>31</sup> The Jews picked up stones **again** to stone Him. <sup>32</sup> Jesus replied to them, “I showed you many good works from the Father; for which of them are you stoning Me?” <sup>33</sup> TThe Jews answered Him, “We are not stoning You for a good work, but for blasphemy; **and** because You, being a man, make Yourself *out to be* God.” (John 10) [NASB]

> <sup>31</sup> ἐβάστασαν πάλιν λίθους οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι ἵνα λιθάσωσιν αὐτόν <sup>32</sup> ἀπεκρίθη αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς πολλὰ ἔργα καλὰ ἔδειξα ὑμῖν ἐκ τοῦ πατρός διὰ ποῖον αὐτῶν ἔργον ἐμὲ λιθάζετε <sup>33</sup> ἀπεκρίθησαν αὐτῷ οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι περὶ καλοῦ ἔργου οὐ λιθάζομέν σε ἀλλὰ περὶ βλασφημίας **καὶ** ὅτι σὺ ἄνθρωπος ὢν ποιεῖς σεαυτὸν θεόν

I believe a main point John makes is they picked up stones **again πάλιν**, and in so doing, the motive behind the first attempt to stone is given. However, I am curious whether John intends the reader to understand two separate reasons:

1. Blasphemy: referring to *Before Abraham was, I am* (8:58)
2. Make yourself God: referring to both *My Father is working until now, and I am working.* (5:17) and *I and the Father are one* (10:30).

Comment: The reasons were the same; the sentences were different.

Comment: This is an important question. Some translations have an 'and', some don't. So some understand blasphemy and 'making yourself 'God'/'a god'' as a clarification, some as a separate reason.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather. The motives of Jesus' accusers to has to be considered. Others side on Jesus' accusers to say that Jesus was making himself equal to God. But what does Jesus' own statement say about equality with God. Jesus himself said the Father is greater than him. Will Jesus answer be disregarded in favor of his accusers? Will we also believe that he has a demon?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Jesus was certainly making himself equal to God *in some sense*, though, right? If the Mayor delegates me the authority to forgive debts, and I go and forgive someone's outstanding property taxes, I *am* claiming a kind of equality to the Mayor, no? That is, the Mayor has authority to forgive debts, *and* I have authority to forgive debts. But, it's delegated. So it's equality in a sense.

Comment: @AlexBalilo If Jesus is indeed the Municipal Messiah (long awaited Chosen One of the Mayor), then it's a legitimate exercise of delegated authority, and so although the charge of equality is correct, it's *legitimate* authority. Or do you think no?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather. If as you say it is "delegated authority" who is the source of this delegated authority? People can make accusations, but how is it determined if the accusation is right? If we believe that what Jesus said was and is the truth, will we believe his accusers instead of his unambiguous statement the the Father is greater than Jesus?

Comment: @RevelationLad. The reason is in John 8:40-44 Ye are of your father the devil, and the lusts of your father it is your will to do. He was a murderer from the beginning, and standeth not in the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh of his own: for he is a liar, and the father thereof.  If their father is the father of lies, is their accusation truthful? Do we believe their accusations instead of Jesus unequivocal "the Father is greater than I" statement?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Right. The source is the Father, the Father is greater than Jesus, no one is good in its most essential sense but the Father, there is only one true God, the Father, and without the Father Jesus can do nothing! He says what the Father tells him to say and does what the Father tells him to do. So the accusers are only correct in a sense. He has equality with God as God's representative and icon - as the one sent by God.

Comment: Wow. Never noticed the 'and' before.

Comment: @RevelationLad. John 10:33, Jesus accusers denied that they were seeking to stone him because of his good work. Does this make their accusation and denial true? they had denied that they were even seeking to kill Jesus earlier (John 7:19,20). To accept as true this accusation would then be like calling Jesus a liar as Jesus pointed out the real reasons why they wished to kill him. Let us see who lied, John 7:19-29 ASV Did not Moses give you the law, and yet none of you doeth the law? Why seek ye to kill me? The multitude answered, Thou hast a demon: who seeketh to kill thee?

Comment: @Revelationlad. Jesus said that his enemiess were not able to comprehend what he was saying to them because they were children of the devil and wanted to do the desires of Satan. They did not accept and understand Jesus because they were not of God. Is it reasonable then to suggest that his accusers have an accurate understanding of Jesus at John 10:33?

Comment: @AlexBalilo One reason they wanted to stone Him is explicitly stated “*For a good work we do not stone You, but for blasphemy, and because You, being a Man, make Yourself God.*” My question is not whether their beliefs were correct, it is whether they wanted to stone Him for blasphemy **and** making Himself God.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Jesus said these men were liars and murderers who wanted to kill him.  Do you take the words of these evil men  as if they were inspired by God?
Jesus said these men could not understand what he was saying because they were evil men who were not of God. If the interpretation you seek relies  n the premise that they understood Jesus,  how then could their accusation be true if Jesus said they did not understand him and were evil men? How can the words of satan's son be true against the words of the son of God.

Comment: There is no *and* in John 10:33 ESV or in any version I saw. You are misquoting it. Correct it with the link for comparison. https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV|version=SBLG|version=NIV|version=NETfull|version=HCSB|version=BSB|reference=John.10.33&options=VGUVNH&display=INTERLEAVED

Comment: @Michael16 The Greek text, both TR and GNT is "...βλασφημίας καὶ ὅτι..." literally *...blasphemy **and** because...* Follow the link you provided and right below the ESV is SBLG which also has "καὶ" -- ἀπεκρίθησαν αὐτῷ οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι· Περὶ καλοῦ ἔργου οὐ λιθάζομέν σε ἀλλὰ περὶ βλασφημίας, **καὶ** ὅτι σὺ ἄνθρωπος ὢν ποιεῖς σεαυτὸν θεόν Apparently the ESV "answered" the question by failing to include καὶ (and) in their translation. There are many translations which have "and:" 
 https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/John%2010:33

Comment: @Michael16 You are correct in that I misidentified the version I quoted. It was not the ESV. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @AlexBalilo If you wish to present a sound exegesis of a passage, I suggest consistency. Example, the same people who you say did not understand Jesus or who He was, claimed He was only a "man." So applying a consistent exegesis would lead you to conclude they were wrong there as well and therefore Jesus was not a man; rather He was God, as the first verse of the Gospel states.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Jesus said he is a man Jn 8:40,  But now ye seek to kill me, a man that hath told you the truth, which I heard from God: this did not Abraham.
Jesus also said that his enemies did not understand him, John 8:43
 43Why do ye not understand my speech? Even because ye cannot hear my word.

Answer (score 4):

The second reason for picking up the stones is the same as before. He was claiming to be the divine Messiah, Son of God. They eagerly pushed him- v24 tell us plainly if you're Christ, so we can stone you.

The conjunction και has the usual connecting in the sense of coordinate, continuative: *and*, adjunctive: *also*. However, it can also have an ascensive sense. This use expresses a final addition or point of focus in a list or argument. It is commonly translated "even". Sometimes και can be translated contrastively "but". NET John 1:17 when law is contrasted with grace. The use of kai is more frequent than the usual usage of *and* in English. It can be left untranslated such as here in [John 10:33](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/10-33.htm).

You can translate και as *even* to show ascensive sense. For even because you being a man make yourself God.

As in 1 Corinthians 2:10: “these things God has revealed to us through the Spirit. For the Spirit searches everything, `και`even the depths of God.”

The use of kai does not necessarily mean giving an *additional* idea in the adjunctive *also* sense. So we can simply keep "and" or leave it untranslated. Consider [these translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/John%2010:33):

> `New Catholic Bible`: The Jews answered, “We are not going to stone you for any good work you have done, but for blasphemy. Even though you are a man, you are claiming to be God.”

> `DLNT` The Jews answered Him, “We do not stone You for a good work, but for blasphemy— even because You, being a human, are making Yourself God

**Conclusion**: John 5:18 gives two reasons, breaking the Sabbath and claiming to be God. In John 10:33 context there's only one reason has been mentioned, that is blasphemy. Breaking Sabbath can't be said as slandering or blaspheming God. Blasphemy is the only reason in this context that is claiming to be Messiah/God.

Comment: Interesting, but where is the kai at 10:33? I can't see one. https://biblehub.com/john/10-33.htm

Comment: See interlinear https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/10-33.htm

Comment: Thanks for that! For some reason, they dropped the kai in the verse link. I cross-checked the Greek texts listed here https://biblehub.com/text/john/10-33.htm and they all have 'kai'.

Comment: That's the question is about.

Comment: John 5:18 gives two reasons, breaking Sabbath and claiming to be God. In John 10:33 context there's only reason of blasphemy mentioned. Breaking Sabbath can't be said as slandering or blaspheming God. Only blasphemy is the reason in this context that is claiming to be Messiah/God

Comment: @Michael16, +1. You should include the essence of your last comment in your anwer.

Comment: 1. How does John use kai? 2. Using John 5:18 (and the subsequent references to that) about work on the Sabbath to eliminate a second reason in John 10 strikes me as avoiding the actual text where the Sabbath is not anywhere mentioned, and specifically excluded (At that time the Feast of Dedication took place at Jerusalem 10:22). That is, you take the previous events of wanting to stone them and assume those are the **only** reasons throughout. So in John 10 there was just one because there is no mention of violating the Sabbath.

Comment: Revelation Lad, you may be just trying to read their minds, and you can add any reasons like jealousy, hatred as your subjective reasons. I don't see any other reason in the context other than the deity/Messiah claims. We have to limit ourselves to the text while interpreting.

Comment: I'm not sure if they wanted to stone him here because they thought He was claiming to be the Christ or something else (but clearly at John 19:7 claiming to be 'the Son of God' is given as a reason for killing him), but I think you're right that as far as they were thinking straight, it was just 1 reason - blasphemy, and that the part after kai is perhaps just spelling out an additional form of blasphemy they want to stone him for or making it clearer.

Comment: kai in Greek is just a more frequent connector than "and"; it can also mean "so" to add coordinating clauses. It doesn't necessarily mean "and" of English.

Comment: "They eagerly pushed him- v24 tell us plainly if you're Christ, so we can stone you." Reflecting more on John 10, I think indeed their intent may have been hostile from the start of the interaction. The surround him. They demand. He says these are people who did not believe. They then sought **again** to seize him (referring to John 7:30?). Seems possible their original intention was simply to have him state clearly He was the Christ so they could have him arrested.

Comment: I think your contention that it is about claiming to be the Christ, the Son of God (both terms used more of less interchangeably) is probably right. John 7:31, just after when hostile Jews try to seize him previously, "Many in the crowd, **however, believed in Him** and said, “When the **Christ** comes, will He perform more signs than this man?”" The debate seems to be about whether He is the Christ, the Son of God. So when Jesus responds about claiming to be the Son of God at 10:36, it's really a debate about being the Christ, the Son of God.

Comment: Exactly, and consequently, being Christ/Son of God implicitly means to be God. He was claiming to be divine (Messiah). Son of God is implicitly understood as God too. It was a true charge that he was making himself equal with God.

Comment: This is all well and good, but "blasphemy" has nothing to do with working on the Sabbath and unless you want to use this event as an illustration (which is circular reasoning), you need to provide some other evidence making yourself "God" is blasphemy. The OT evidence seems to show blasphemy is more narrowly focused on misusing the name.

Comment: Blasphemy was the charge made by his enemies. John doesn't affirm it. He affirms that he was claiming to be Messiah/God, but this was blasphemy to others.

Comment: "Blasphemy was the charge made by His enemies..." that is the question. What reason or reasons did His enemies have for stoning Him? Obviously Jesus did not agree with any of their reasons for wanting to stone Him. But that does not speak to the reasoning of His enemies.

Comment: I should have put more detail.. Your points 1)blasphemy and 2) old references about equality with father. This is conjecture, coz the context doesn't show that. The *and* simply shows the ascensive meaning *even*: "(not only) for blasphemy, but even though you being a man"; these aren't 2 separate reasons but ascensive reason (2 aspects of same reason); not only you generally implicitly blaspheme, but you even explicitly call urself god. This is why the translations remove "and" for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

In John 5, "making himself equal with God" was more subtle.  It didn't get the public to pick up stones.

> 18 This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.
> (John 5:18, ESV)

In John 8:28 and 8:58 what Jesus said translated ἐγώ εἰμι the public directly understood Jesus claiming to be God so they picked up stones.  See [What did Jesus likely say in John 8:58?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/what-did-jesus-likely-say-in-john-858/39133#39133)

By that time the Jews did not pronounce the divine name YHWH (consonants with vowels forgotten).  When reading scripture they would say Adonai (Lord) when they came to YHWH.  Thus, they understood Jesus as claiming to be God.

Comment: " what Jesus said translated ἐγώ εἰμι the public directly understood Jesus claiming to be God so they picked up stones" Except Jesus just before in John 8 states they're trying to kill him, *before* they pick up stones. John 7 makes clear the authorities had decided Jesus was not in fact the Messiah, the Son of God.

Comment: Hatred against Jesus, his claims, and what he did, began as early on as Jesus forgiving the sins of the paralytic lowered through the ceiling (proven by healing him). Mark ch.2 has the shocked religious legalists thinking to themselves "Who can forgive sins, but God alone?" Jesus knew what they were thinking - another divine prerogative. They began scheming to get rid of him very early on in his ministry because they knew such divine powers threatened their authority. This went deeper than Jesus pronouncing the divine Name!

Answer (score 3):

In order to place this question in context, I have listed in the appendix 1 below all the examples in the Gospels where the Jews determined to kill Jesus and why.

Their reasons all boil down to just two:

- Jesus was accused of blasphemy, ie, being God or being equal with God
- Jesus undermined the Jew's authority by showing that there was no basis for their spiritual pride and arrogance - these occurred more often that the above reason.

In the specific case of the examples in John 5, 8 and 10 (#3, #4, and #5) in the list of appendix 1 below, all are associated with the charge of blasphemy in various ways: either being equal to God, being one with the Father, or acting directly by God's power by unity with Him, etc.

These were all different aspects of the same charge of blasphemy, ie, the claim to be God.  For example, claiming (apart from being the "I AM") to have existed before Abraham, effectively makes Jesus either divine or something that the Jews could not grasp (and unstated).

**APPENDIX 1 Intentions to Kill Jesus**

Here is a list of the nine or ten times the Gospels record that Jesus said or did something that the Jews regarded worthy of Jesus' death.  This does not include Herod's attempt to kill Jesus soon after His birth.

1. **Luke 4:16-30 - Jesus quotes Isa 61:1, 2 to begin His ministry**

It appears that when Jesus said that he would no perform miracles in Nazareth because for the same reason that Elijah got help from outsiders they wanted to kill Him.  Thus, they would not accept a hometown prophet.

This wounded their spiritual pride and they tried to kill Jesus (V28-30) but Jesus escaped.

2. **Matt 12:1-14; Mark 2:23-3:6; Luke 6:1-11 - Jesus claimed to be Lord of the Sabbath and heal on the Sabbath**

Again, Jesus' claims outraged their confected spiritual pride and they wanted to kill Him.

3. **John 5:1-18 - Healing at the pool of Bethesda**

In V18, it appears that the Jews wanted to kill Jesus, not because of the healing but because He told a man to pick up his bed on the Sabbath.  Again, this wounded their spiritual pride and undermined their authority.

However, there is a subtlety here - Jesus' defense against the charge of Sabbath breaking involved Him essentially saying that because He and the Father are always working, including on Sabbath, the healing was legal.  Thus, there was also a component of blasphemy in this as well because Jesus claimed to be making Himself equal with God, because it was OK for God to be working on Sabbath.

4. **John 8:48-59 - Jesus claimed to be the "I AM"**

There are possibly two components to this answer of Jesus - His claim to be the "I AM" of the OT and His claim to pre-existence before Abraham and thus greater than Abraham; but this is not explicit.

5. **John 10:22-39 - Jesus claims to be equal to God**

There are two attempts to kill Jesus here:

- A. John 5:22-31 - This is a clear instance of Jesus claiming equality of God by an allusion to the Shema in Deut 6:4
- B. John 5:32-39 - Again, Jesus' claim at complete unity with God makes Him equal with God and thus guilty of Blasphemy

6. **John 11:45-57 - Raising of Lazarus**

In this case, the Jews' hatred was based upon the undeniable fact that Jesus was undermining their authority and privileged position

7. **Mark 11:15-18; Luke 19:45-48 - Final Cleansing of the Temple**

This is another instance where the Jews' hatred of Jesus was based upon the fact that Jesus was undermining their authority and privileged position

8. **Matt 21:33-46; Mark 12:1-12; Luke 20:9-19 - "Kingdom taken from you"**

Yet another case where the Jews' hatred of Jesus was based upon the fact that Jesus was undermining their authority and privileged position

9. **Matt 26:57-67; Mark 14:53-65; Luke 22:66-71; John 18:19-24 - Accused of blasphemy**

It was at this trial that Jesus accused of blasphemy because of two components of His reply:

- Jesus claims to be the "I AM" in Mark 14:62, Luke 22:70
- Jesus claims to be the prophesied coming divine king in Matt 26:64

At Jesus' trials before the high Priest and partial Sanhedrin, we observe three things:

- Jesus' arrest was the result of the accumulated and growing hatred of Jesus, primarily based upon Jesus' necessary undermining of the fake authority of the Jewish leadership
- In order to get "an almost" valid reason to execute Jesus, the Sanhedrin fastened upon Jesus supposed crime of blasphemy (Matt 26:64, 65)
- This charge of blasphemy mysteriously morphed into sedition between the Sanhedrin and Pilate's trial

**APPENDIX 2 - Jesus' "I AM" Claims**

Here is a list of Jesus' explicit "I AM" claims in the Gospels which allude to many such in the OT applied to God.

- Matt 14:27, Mark 6:50 – “Be encouraged.  I am.”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- Mark 14:62, Luke 22:70 – “Jesus replied, ‘I am’”.  [He was then accused of blasphemy by the Jews and condemned.]
- John 4:26 – “Then Jesus said, ‘I am.’”  [To the Samaritan woman at the well.  There is a reasonable case for this being identification, but that is a matter of taste.]
- John 6:20 – “But then [Jesus] said to them, ‘I am.  Fear not.’”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- John 8:24 – “If you do not trust/believe that I am, you will die in your sins.”
- John 8:28 – “When you will lift up the Son of Man, then you will trust/know that I am.”
- John 8:58 – “Truly, truly, I say to you; before Abraham existed, I am.”  [The Jews then tried to stone Him for blasphemy.]  Note that this and the previous two mean that Jesus, in the space of this chapter of John 8 uses the unpredicated “I am” idea in the present (v24), future (v28) and past sense (v58).  V24 & 28 appears to be tied to believers’ salvation as well.
- John 13:19 – “From now [on] I tell you before the occurrence, that you may believe when it occurs that, I am.”
- John 18: 5, 6, 8 – “He said to them, ‘I am.’ …Therefore, when He told them, ‘I am’, they fell backward to the ground.”  [This occurred when the Jews tried to arrest Jesus in the garden.  It could be reasonably argued that this is a case of identification.  However, the fact that the arresting mob fell backward suggests that much more is intended here.]

Significantly, according to Mark 13:6 and Luke 21:8, one of the distinguishing characteristics of false christs is their claim to be “I AM”.  Unfortunately, there has been a historical parade of charlatans making such false claims.

Comment: When you say, 'In order to get "an almost" valid reason to execute Jesus, the Sanhedrin fastened upon Jesus [the] supposed crime of blasphemy' - bear in mind that they genuinely took his claims to be blasphemous. They could only be blasphemous if they were true, and Jesus truly made those stupendous claims about himself. As by then it was illegal for them to stone anyone to death, and Jesus escaped, they knew they had to concoct a political charge for Rome to do their dirty work. There was no mystery at accusing Jesus of sedition before Pilate! Blasphemy wouldn't wash with Pilate!

Comment: Your answer does not address the situation in John. It may be true that a claim to be God is always considered to be blasphemy, but it is not true that a charge of blasphemy is limited to making a claim to be God. The root meaning of the word is an act of effrontery in which the honor of God is insulted by man. For example, "*and the Israelite woman's son blasphemed the Name, and cursed...*" Leviticus 24:11.

Comment: @Anne - first, thanks for fixing my ever-present typos.  I fully agree with you comments (the trials were illegal anyway).

Comment: @RevelationLad - I agree with your comments about blasphemy.  However, in every case associated with Jesus, the blasphemy charge was associated with His claims to be God in some sense, especially in John.  This is part of John's central dual purpose in writing his gospel - to show that Jesus was fully human and fully God and uses antagonistic witnesses to show that even they knew of Jesus' claims to be God.

Comment: @RevelationLad - I have considered this further and have added some material in appendix 1 about the charge of blasphemy.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Both reasons are about the same: “My Father is working until now and I work”, here “now” expresses eternity, for in the dimension of time, the changeless eternity is expressed only by “now” in virtue of the latter having no past no future, but representing an in itself self-complete, changeless instance.

Thus, if both Father and the Son act “now”, this means that They Both act changelessly and eternally, which means that activity of Both is one activity. If so, then the Father and the Son are one in virtue of Their activity being always mutual and inseparable, for Father can do anything only through and together with the Son. When the Lord says “on My own I can do nothing, but what the Father shows Me”, does it mean that Father does some things independently from the Son, and other things He shows to the Son and They do them jointly? Stupid even to entertain such absurdity! Of course Father cannot but “show” all His actions to the Son and do all His deeds and actions through and jointly with the Son.

Therefore the Son is co-eternal with the Father and co-uncreated. Therefore, before Abraham was, the Son *is*, which present tense expresses the “now of eternity” and the divine atemporality.

This sounded a blasphemy of duo-theism for some Jews who took stones against Him for that reason.

Comment: @Down-voter Hey, my Arian down-voter pal! Why do not you bother to lay down your precious objections for me? I am ashamed for you with a “Spanish shame” if you are unable to do so.

Comment: I like this answer as well. +1.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili,. The people that see the votes on this site know who downvoted you but you already assume it is an Arian.

Comment: @Dottard Thanks dear Dottard! - tried to be worthy of those great theological statements in my comment on them.

Comment: +1 An interesting line of argument, tho' a bit speculative. "My Father is working until eternity?" That sounds really strange, a clash of temporal terms.

Comment: +1 But is this reason separate from blasphemy?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Action of eternal God in history is a mystery. Human language and grammar can fail, utterly so. Moreover, I did not write “now” of time is eternity, but that it expresses the duration-less-ness and eternity. Thanks for your interest and upvote.

Comment: @RevelationLad blasphemy? Why?

Comment: Because they picked up stones **again**; the first time recorded was 8:59, after saying "I am."

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely two reasons given why they want to cast stones at Jesus.  Therefore the word "and" is appropriate since both of them in their minds deserve stoning.

In the first one the Jews are  incensed that Jesus told the man who had been healed of his infirmity to pick up his pallet and walk on the Sabbath.  Not only did Jesus break the Sabbath they said but said His own Father also is God, making himself equal to God.

He then explained to them that it was His Father  who is working and therefore he was working also.  This now doubly incensed them because not only is He working on the Sabbath, but said his own Father also is God, making Himself equal to God.

"The charge of  equality with God brings out a clear statement of the relationship of the Son to the Father.  Of Himself the Son is unable to do anything. He does not claim divine power independent of the Father.   Neither does He claim to exercise His own will.  That is God's prerogative.  (Verse 30)
As He has neither the ability nor the will of the Father, the charge of making Himself equal with God was false.
He did not exercise His own will  and because He did nothing except by the power
and sanction of the Father, and was sent and commissioned by Him.  He is entitled to all the honor due to the Father,  for only thus can the Father receive the homage of His creatures. The healing of the impotent man was done by the power and will of the Father.  If it was a desecration of the Sabbath , then  the Father was responsible.  Concordant Commentary"

> I can do nothing of myself.  According I am hearing am I judging; And my judgment is just, seeing that I am not seeking my will, but the will of Him who sends me.  John 5:30

> And because of this were the Jews persecuting Jesus, and seeking to kill him, because these things he was doing on a sabbath. And Jesus answered them, ‘My Father till now doth work, and I work;’
> Because of this, then, were the Jews seeking the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the sabbath, but he also called God his own Father, making himself equal to God.

He tells them plainly He only does what the Father does, He  is a doing the works  of God in the flesh.  God the Father is doing His work through His Son who is expressing the Fathers will and desire.

In the second verse OP is referring to is John 10:31-33 It is where the Jews want to stone Him for blasphemy, and that you being a man are making yourself God.

> “For a good work we do not stone You, but for blasphemy, and because You, being a Man, make Yourself God.” John 10:32-34

In the very next verse Jesus answers them from a quote from Psalm 82.

> Jesus answered them, "Is it not written in your law, that "I said you are gods'?  And he said those were gods to whom the word of God came (And the scripture cannot be annulled) , are you saying to Him Whom the Father hallows and dispatches into the world that "You are blaspheming," Saying that I said, "I am the Son of God"?

"The term "gods" is translated
"judges" in Ex. 21:6; 22:8-9 where it refers to men.  But our Lord does not appeal to this, but to Psalm 82:6 where  the context clearly excludes men.  The mighty spiritual powers of wickedness who overrule the affairs of mankind are called sons by God Himself.  Even Satan is called a son of God. (Job 1:6) He is called the god of the eon (2Co.4:4) Now if God said to him and his host, "Ye are gods", Not withstanding the fact that they failed to right the wrongs of earth, how much rather shall He have called Him God Who shall disposses them?  To Him God says (Psa. 82:8)

> Rise, oh God! Judge the earth,
> For thou shall be allotted all nations.

He had been undoing the deeds of these sons of God and doing all that was foretold
of Him before their very eyes.  And yet they thought they were not blind!  Concordant and Commentary"

In both of these accusations The Lord sets them straight.

He was not deserving of one stone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address this question by going to the trial record first and work backwards. At Matthew 26:61 one of the false witnesses states, "This man stated, I am able to destroy this temple of God and rebuild it in three days."

Remember Jesus said those words about three years ago and the Apostle John said at John 2:21, "But He was speaking of the temple of His body."

Now, It seems to me whether or not the Jews are correctly or incorrectly understanding Jesus is not the issue. The issue is what was it that Jesus said that caused them to say he was claiming to be God that so upset them?

What did Jesus say at John 5:17-18? And btw, Jesus called God His Father at Luke 2:49 when he was twelve years old. Moving on to John 8:56-59, Jesus claiming to exist before Abraham "sprang" into existence.

Now to John 10:30. Jesus says, "I and the Father "We" are one." Here Jesus was claiming He was one in nature/essence. The Jews clearly understood what Jesus meant from John 10:33 saying, "You being a man make yourself out God."

Now getting back to the trial record the high priest Caiaphas ask Jesus vs63, (after the testimony of the false witnesses), "I adjure You by the living God, that You tell us whether (1) You are the Christ/Messiah and (2) the Son of God."

In other words, the high priest is asking Jesus to swear as to His identity. At Luke 22:70 Jesus says, "Yes, I am."

At Matthew 26:44 the high priest reacts, "Then the high priest tore his robes saying. "He has blasphemed! What further need do we have of witnesses? Behold, you have now heard the blasphemy:"

As a side note! If the Jews did not understand anything Jesus was saying why would the high priest quote the law of blasphemy at Leviticus 24:16?

I think it's pretty clear that the only conclusion one can come to is that Jesus is claiming to be God (without actually saying the words "I am God") and the Jews understood the claim.

Comment: +1 ""I adjure You by the living God, that You tell us whether (1) You are the Christ/Messiah **and** (2) the Son of God."" There's no 'and' at Matthew 26:63, tho'.

Comment: "I think it's pretty clear that the **only conclusion** one can come to is that Jesus is claiming to be God" Can you say more about why the only conclusion is a claim to be Yahweh? Blasphemy laws include more than just that, no?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I know there is no "and" in there but I used it for clarity. The word "whether" is indicating that a statement applies whichever of the alternatives mentioned is the case. In this case (Matthew 26:63 the high priest is asking two questions? (1) Are you the Christ/Messiah? (2) Are you the Son of God? Also, it is not blasphemy to claim to be the Messiah. Many people (from Jesus' day) and even today have made the claim and they are killed. Moreover, why was Jesus accused of blasphemy for being the Son of God when the Jews claim they are sons of God as well?

Comment: "is asking two questions" Well, perhaps. But that's a major question. They seem to just be run together often, where the two terms are co-referents used to 'disambiguate' the referent. If someone said "Are you the anointed" that wouldn't be clear enough in certain circumstances, so "the son of god" is added. Anyway, that seems like a possible option.

Comment: But one major option seems to be that falsely claiming to be the Christ, the Son of God is indeed blasphemy. The Jewish elite had already decided he wasn't. If they didn't know, then they didn't know, and it might or might not be blasphemy. But if they did know he wasn't, it was blasphemy.

Comment: That Jesus seems intent on hiding this identity as the Christ, the Son of God, from the elite, and if He knew they would consider that claim by him blasphemy and then kill him for it, that makes sense.

Comment: Jesus is not trying to hide His identity. He wants us to come to that conclusion like Peter did at Matthew 16:16 "Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God." So in what respect is Jesus the Son of God? Please read Matthew 22:42-46.   for the answer. You will also find why John wrote his gospel. John 31. "but these have been written that you may believe that Jesus is the 1-the Christ, 2- the Son of God; and believing that you may have life in His name." See that, coming to your own conclusion based on the evidence. Jesus is literally the Son of God and Christians are adopted sons of God.

Comment: What exactly is your point re Matt 22:42-46? Re John 20:31, again though, it's ambiguous. Is John simply using 2 co-referents to point out 1 identity? Or is he intending to make 2 distinct claims? My guess is it's the former.

Answer (score 0):

Leviticus 24:16

> anyone who **blasphemes** the name of the LORD is to be put to death. The entire assembly must stone them. Whether foreigner or native-born, when they blaspheme the Name they are to be put to death.

John 10:

> 33 The Jews answered Him, saying, “For a good work we do not stone You, **but for blasphemy**, and because You, being a Man, make Yourself God.”

Are there two separate reasons given for wanting to stone Jesus?

There were a thousand illegal reasons why they wanted to stone Jesus but there was only one legal reason: blasphemy.

Comment: "There were a thousand reasons..." John speaks of blasphemy **and** because you make yourself God. That is either 1 or 2.

Comment: Good point. I added.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in John 8:40-44 Ye are of your father the devil, and the lusts of your father it is your will to do. He was a murderer from the beginning, and standeth not in the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh of his own: for he is a liar, and the father thereof.  If their father is the father of lies, is their accusation truthful? Do we believe their accusations instead of Jesus unequivocal "the Father is greater than I" statement?

John 8:40-44 ASV

40But now ye seek to kill me, a man that hath told you the truth, which I heard from God: this did not Abraham. 41Ye do the works of your father. They said unto him, We were not born of fornication; we have one Father, even God.

42Jesus said unto them, If God were your Father, ye would love me: for I came forth and am come from God; for neither have I come of myself, but he sent me. 43Why do ye not understand my speech? Even because ye cannot hear my word. 44Ye are of your father the devil, and the lusts of your father it is your will to do. He was a murderer from the beginning, and standeth not in the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh of his own: for he is a liar, and the father thereof

Jesus’ statements in John 5:19 show that he had been sent by God. He is not God and that he admitted that he could do nothing on his own, but only what the Father willed:

John 5:19 ASV Jesus therefore answered and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father doing: for what things soever he doeth, these the Son also doeth in like manner.

Does John 5:19  make sense if Jesus is the Almighty God and as God he did only what he was directed to do? Consider Psalm 135:6 ASV Whatsoever Jehovah pleased, that hath he done, In heaven and in earth, in the seas and in all deeps; and Isaiah 46:9-10 ASV Remember the former things of old: for I am God, and there is none else; I am God, and there is none like me 10 declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times things that are not yet done; saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all my pleasure; God says he does what he pleases while Jesus said he "can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father doing: for what things soever he doeth, these the Son also doeth in like manner."

Further reading of John chapter 5 reveals that Jesus did not claim to be God. Jesus claimed to have been sent by God which the Jews refused to accept, John 5:37-38,43.

John 5:37-38 ASV And the Father that sent me, he hath borne witness of me. Ye have neither heard his voice at any time, nor seen his form And ye have not his word abiding in you: for whom he sent, him ye believe not.

John 5:43 ASV  I am come in my Father's name, and ye receive me not: if another shall come in his own name, him ye will receive.

**Blasphemy: referring to Before Abraham was, I am (8:58)**

The Jews have already sought to kill him before this, John 7:1 John 7:25

John 7:1 ASV And after these things Jesus walked in Galilee: for he would not walk in Judea, because the Jews sought to kill him.

John 7:25 ASV And the men from Jerusalem were saying, “Is This not he whom they seek to kill?"

Young's Analytical Concordance to the Holy Bible in explaining John 8:58 tells us that Jesus was proclaiming himself by these words (ego eimi) to be "the promised Messiah." - Young's Concise Critical Bible Commentary, p. 61, 1977 ed., Baker Book House.

Are the words "I am" God's name? What sense would John 8:58 make if it is. Consider Jesus saying, "Most assuredly I say to you, **before Abraham was YHWH?**

Others say that IAM is YHWH. Let's see. Is the angel Gabriel YHWH too? Luke 1:19. Did Peter said YHWH is prepared to to to prison with Jesus? Luke 22:33 Is YHWH a man under authority, Matthew 8:9.

Luke 1:19 ASV And the angel answering said unto him, **I am** Gabriel, that stand in the presence of God; and I was sent to speak unto thee, and to bring thee these good tidings

Luke 22:33 ASV And he said unto him, Lord, with thee **I am** ready to go both to prison and to death

**Make yourself God: referring to both My Father is working until now, and I am working. (5:17) and I and the Father are one (10:30)**

The equality topic shown in the context was that Jesus was claiming the same right as his Father (my Father is working) to heal/ do good on the Sabbath. John 7:22-23 shows that the forefathers of the Jews circumcised on the Sabbath. Matthew 12:9-14 also show that it is lawful to do good on a sabbath.

Examining the context of John 10, we find that those that put faith in Jesus did not believe the accusation that Jesus was making himself equal to God. John 10:40-42 "everything John said about this **man** Jesus, (**not God**) was true. John 10:40-42

John 10:40-42 ASV And he went away again beyond the Jordan into the place where John was at the first baptizing; and there he abode. And many came unto him; and they said, John indeed did no sign: but all things whatsoever John spake of this **man** were true. And many believed on him there

Jesus enemies used this as an excuse, for they had long been seeking an excuse to kill him. (Matthew 12:14; Mark 3:6; 11:18, John 5:18; 7:19,20; 8:37) as was already pointed out in John 7:1 Jesus enemies were seeking to kill him. They have proven  themselves liars in  (John 7:19,20) when they were confronted by Jesus. In Luke 6:7 we find the Jewish leaders were watching him that they might find an accusation against him. In Luke 11:54, we see that they were lying in wait for him, and seeking to catch him in something he might say, that they might accuse him.

Matthew 12:14 ASV But the Pharisees went out, and took counsel against him, how they might destroy him.

Mark 3:6 ASV And the Pharisees went out, and straightway with the Herodians took counsel against him, how they might destroy him

Mark 11:18 ASV And the chief priests and the scribes heard it, and sought how they might destroy him: for they feared him, for all the multitude was astonished at his teaching.

Luke 6:7 ASV And the scribes and the Pharisees watched him, whether he would heal on the sabbath; that they might find how to accuse him.

Luke 11:54 ASV laying wait for him, to catch something out of his mouth.

John 7:19-29 ASV Did not Moses give you the law, and yet none of you doeth the law? Why seek ye to kill me? The multitude answered, Thou hast a demon: who seeketh to kill thee?

In John 10:33, Jesus accusers denied that they were seeking to stone him because of his good work. Does this make their accusation and denial true? Yhey had  denied that they were even seeking to kill Jesus earlier (John 7:19,20). To accept as true  this accusation would be calling Jesus a liar. Jesus pointed out the real reasons why they wished to kill him.

Comment: The question is why did **the Jews** try to stone Jesus? If they understood Him as consistently and conclusively, as you claim, denying His divinity, why did they try to stone *because we are going to stone you but for blasphemy, and because you, being a man, make yourself God*?

Comment: @RevelationLad. John 8:40-44. Jesus very clearly stated the reason why they wanted to kill him. From that reason you can clearly see that the accusation is false. If you believe his accusers whose father is the devil, then you believe that their accusation to be true. Examine the context and there is nothing there that says he made himself God. Was Jesus tried for making himself God? Or was he tried by claiming to be the Christ?

Comment: This is a really good summary of some things going on in John. I think you're right that John 10:41 is an important clue. The people who believed seemed to think unproblematically of Jesus as a man. So I think you're right that the ultimate source of the charges is to be found in John 8:40-44. The hostile Jewish elite simply doesn't understand him, including at 10:33. So I think what you're saying here is correct in the ultimate sense, but I'm trying to figure out the proximate reasons the hostile Jews are thinking of.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather. The closest one I see is their accusation about Jesus breaking the Sabbath..Jesus' my Father is working and I am working" statement was taken as breaking God's laws and claiming the same authority /right to work on the sabbath as Jesus' Father is working on the sabbath.