Is there a consensus in the Greek scholars‘ or translation experts community as to the scientific value of „Truth in Translation“ of Debuhn?
Jason Debuhn‘s work „Truth in Translation“ is cited by Jehovah‘s Witnesses as a scholar‘s support of their widely contested New World Translation. Is there a common consensus on the person of professor Debuhn in general as a Greek scholar (acc. to his homepage he holds no degree in Greek) and his work „Truth in…“?

The errors of translation in the NWT are frequent and flagrant about which I have written on this site, eg, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/how-accurate-is-the-new-world-translation-bible/76272#76272  On the subject of Jason Debuhn's view on the NWT, any quick internet search shows that his views are shared by a very round number of eminent scholars (ie, zero).

Thank you for the hint.

Truth in Translation: Accuracy and Bias in English Translations of the New Testament

The book serves to inform readers of the forces at work shaping the
meaning of the Bible, to help in their selection of Bible
translations, and to act as a critical catalyst for the improvement of
Bible translations through more careful attention to the risk of bias
in the translation process.


BeDuhn’s academic background:
Jason BeDuhn holds  [1] [2] 

a B.A. in Religious Studies from the University of Illinois at
Urbana–Champaign
an M.T.S. in New Testament and Christian Origins from Harvard
Divinity School
and a Ph.D. in the Comparative Study of Religions from Indiana
University Bloomington


I found a scholarly review by Dr. Jason Harris:
Pros:

It is a scholarly work. At the very least the book is carefully
crafted and shows that BeDuhn’s did extensive research.
It challenges mainstream evangelicalism’s assumption that any Bible
translation will suffice. He argues that too often, even in mainstream translations, the translators make the subtle journey from translation to interpretation.
He argues that the chapter “The Work of Translation” is very helpful in explaining
the spectrum of translation philosophies from Interlinear to Formal
Equivalence, Dynamic Equivalence, and Paraphrase.

Cons:

He lacks awareness.: Dr. Jason Harris notes that BeDuhn seems unaware of the modern debate on translations, especially within
Christian Fundamentalism. Apparently BeDuhn made a statement that
seemed to indicate that he hadn’t studied the preface of the 1611 Authorised Version even though he was trying to make a point about it.
Does he actually avoid bias in his analysis?: BeDuhn claims to avoid bias but doesn’t reveal his own theological biases. Admitting
his position early on would have built more trust with readers.
Is BeDuhn’s neutrality neutral?: BeDuhn’s neutrality on the deity of Jesus Christ raises the question about his epistemology. Why? Because isn't not presupposing the deity of Christ in translation akin to presupposing the non-deity of Christ?
BeDuhn fails to acknowledge that all translation involves
interpretation. Choosing English words involves various arguments,
including interpretative ones.
Selection bias?: BeDuhn’s selection of passages seems to shows bias because he is focusing mainly on the deity of Jesus Christ. He
deals with passages consistent with the deity of Christ but not
necv,
Proof vs. consistency: BeDuhn doesn’t distinguish between passages
that prove a point and those consistent with a point. Treating these
equally obscures translation complexities.
Credibility: Oddly, BeDuhn dismisses established Greek grammar rules
like Colwell’s Rule and the Granville Sharp rule, aParticularly, he
addresses Colwell’s Rule and the Granville Sharp rule. Instead of
merely critiquing them and offering adjustments or developments to
them, in both cases he simply says they are wrong and should be
ignored.


Thanks for this analysis, very helpful.
